# Orthonomal bases and cross products

Tags: linear-algebra, multivariable-calculus

I want to show that if I have an orthonormal basis of $\mathbb{R}^3$, say $\{\boldsymbol{u}, \boldsymbol{v}, \boldsymbol{w}\}$, and if $\boldsymbol{u} × \boldsymbol{v} = \boldsymbol{w}$, then we have that $\boldsymbol{v} × \boldsymbol{w} = \boldsymbol{u}$ and that $\boldsymbol{w} × \boldsymbol{u} = \boldsymbol{v}$.

From $\boldsymbol{u} × \boldsymbol{v} = \boldsymbol{w}$ I know I can write $\boldsymbol{w}$'s coordinates in terms of $\boldsymbol{u}$ and $\boldsymbol{v}$'s coordinates. More precisely, I know I can write $\langle w_1, w_2, w_3 \rangle = \langle u_2v_3 - u_3v_2, u_3v_1 - u_1v_3, u_1v_2 - u_2v_1 \rangle$. Then in computing $\boldsymbol{v} × \boldsymbol{w}$, I can substitute wherever I see coordinates of $\boldsymbol{w}$ to get a vector only in terms of $\boldsymbol{u}$ and $\boldsymbol{v}$.

However, I'm getting stuck and don't know where to use that 1. each of the vectors are unit length and 2. they are pairwisely orthogonal.

Comment: Actually it is quite easy, you know that cross product of two vector should be perpendicular these two, since your base is normalized it's magnitude equals to 1. Only thing you have to prove is v x w = -u or u, Assume the first, but  -w = v x ( v x w )  = v x (-u) = u x v  = w, But this is contradiction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the vector identity ORA-OAR :
$$
        A \times (B \times C) = (A \cdot C) B - (A\cdot B) C
$$
Therefore, if $\{ u,v,w \}$ is an orthonormal basis, and $w = u \times v$, then $v\cdot v = 1$ and $v\cdot u=0$, which gives
$$
      v\times w = v \times (u \times v) = (v\cdot v)u-(v\cdot u)v=u.
$$
Similarly,
$$
            w\times u = (u\times v)\times u = (u\cdot u)v-(u\cdot v)u=v.
$$

Answer (score 0):

We have $$v\times w=\langle v\times w,u\rangle u+\langle v\times w,v\rangle v +\langle v\times w,w\rangle w=\langle v\times w,u\rangle u=-\langle w, v\times u\rangle u=\langle w,u\times v\rangle u=\langle w,w\rangle u=u.$$